# LXDE plugin directory

Tags: lxde

I'm following [this](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel) tutorial from [the lxde wiki](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel).

I'm able to follow along and compile the plugin, however I don't know where to place the resulting object file.

The tutorial says:

> After placing the resulting test.so file in /usr/lib/lxpanel/plugins (the place may be different depending on your distro, look where LXPanel puts other dynamic plugins), restart the panel (using lxpanelctl restart), then right-click on the panel and attempt to add a plugin to the panel

My system didn't have that directory, so I created it. However, the plugin still doesn't appear in the list of available plugins after copying the object file and "restarting the panel". I'm pretty certain I need to copy the object file to a different location, but I'm not sure where that is or how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my distro (Ubuntu Server 18) it was at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins` however a good way to find it is using the `find` command in combination with `grep`.

Personally I used this command to find my plugins directory:
`find / 2>/dev/null | grep lxpanel | grep weather.so`
And thats assuming your installation came with the default LXDE weather plugin